# Need advice on node.js / DB structure

Tags: node.js, database

The project I am working on wil be deployed to multiple "rooms". Each room has it's own server, running an instance of node.js, and each room will have some form of data storage. (database flavour is not determined yet).

Each room must be able to operate completely on it's own... so if we have 5 rooms, and 4 rooms are shut down, the last one should be able to keep working without the others. No problems so far...

The tricky part is that there is some shared data between the rooms... user accounts for example. So if one room adds a user, that user should be able to log in in all the rooms.
It would also be nice if the node.js instances could be notified if one of the other rooms makes a change to a record, so that they can reload that data if needed...

I have been looking at MongoDB replica sets, but am not convinced that that is the best solution for my problem.

I also have been thinking about a solution where each room is responsible for its DB, and updates it when an other node.js instance broadcasts an event signalling a new user. The problem there is that if a room has been offline for a day, it will not catch up with the changes made during its down-time.

We're not looking at huge amounts of data here... anyone here with sufficient DB knowledge to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need for every room to have a database of it's own.**

What you are looking to do is to have a single central Database which can be SQL/NoSQL. This central database can be clustered on multiple machines for reliability, availability, data sharding, load balancing and the many other benefits of having a database cluster instead of a single machine. The way this can be done is different for different database systems. There's plenty out there: **mysql, redis, postgresql and many others.** You can take a look at them.

All your node instances would write and read from that central database. There would be no need for instances to notify each other and update their own local databases when a new user is added somewhere. This is totally not necessary. In this case, even if a node is offline for a day, it would be able to access all the fresh data from the central database when back online again. This is the design you should follow.

Having multiple database instances, one for each room and implementing a coordination layer on the server level is a total NO. This coordination should be done at the database layer itself and all server instances should be able to contact the database which in turn is consistent and updated.

I hope this answer helps guiding you.